# Deploy my messenger chatBot on my online server

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, ngrok, facebook-chatbot

I'm working on a facebook messenger chatbot  ( dialogFlow and nodejs and ngrok )

and every time i test the chatbot in my local server (pc or mac)

- run node index.js
- i run the ngrok proxy server
- copy  the ngrok server url  to facebook app

So now i want to deploy the chatbot on my online server ( linux ) ? 
Do you have any idea how to do it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use services such as Heroku in order to do so. If you launch it on your own Linux server, you should have a URL pointing to it (i.e: mylinuxserver.com) and as your nodeJS code is listening to a route it will work the same as ngrok :) (i.e: mylinuxserver.com/bot)